# cURL POST bash script adds single quotes to variables with spaces

Tags: linux, bash, curl, shell-scripting

The first 3 variables will always have no spaces. The fourth "`slacksitename`" has spaces

```
ip=“x.x.x.x"
record_name=“demo.xyz"
slackuri:”WEBHOOK"
slacksitename:”123 Main St"
```

When called with cURL

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"’$slacksitename': '$ip' '$record_name' DDNS updated.”}’ $slackuri
```

The output is as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"123' Main 'St: x.x.x.x demo.xyz DDNS updated."}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/……..
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Main
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 59:
St: x.x.x.x demo.xyz DDNS updated."
```

**Would anyone know why it's adding the single quotes to `123' Main 'St`? And how I'd get that to treat the entire variable as one string instead of splitting it (which is what I think it's doing)?**

Thanks

**UPDATE: Solved^^**

*Follow Up:*

This probably falls along the same lines of the original quetion:

I have a variable that is a JSON output that I want to send via cURL. I'm Assuming the issue is quotations again but the JSON output may change (Number of quotes). Is there any way of sending this raw data with cURL in the message with a new line? Thanks

```
DUMPING RESULTS:\n{"result":{"id":"ppbkbz2ezmxen11vvpi65chsro1vki5y","zone_id":"unuM0sR1gSrQ37r9fGC1sYKFZOP0DzJM","zone_name":"demo.xyz","name":"1.demo.xyz","type":"A","content":"x.x.x.x","proxiable":true,"proxied":false,"ttl":1,"locked":false,"meta":{"auto_added":false,"managed_by_apps":false,"managed_by_argo_tunnel":false,"source":"primary"},"created_on":"2020-06-14T19:13:57.096688Z","modified_on":"2021-10-16T16:57:49.269274Z"},"success":true,"errors":[],"messages":[]}."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using unquoted variables in bash and look surprised that word splitting happens. This is what's supposed to happen.

You also have non-standard quotes in your question that I'll assume are because of automatic formatting. But note that `"` is not the same as `”` and `'` is not the same as `ʼ`.

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"’$slacksitename': '$ip' '$record_name' DDNS updated.”}’ $slackuri`

In your command line, you're quoting `{"text":"` and appending the unquoted content of `$slacksitename` to it, which means word splitting will take place on it. The end result will be 3 separate arguments: `{"text":"123`, `Main`, `St`. The third argument will be concatenated with `:`  which will itself be concatenated with the content of the unquoted `$ip` so we're any spaces present in that variable, the same would happen.

This is essentially bash 101, quote your variables unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `”` and `ʼ` were by mistake and not actually in the script. I'm a bit lost though on how to solve this. I get what you're saying as far as unquoted variables causing issues. But I'm not sure how a correctly quoted variable would look like. Sorry to be such a noob. Could you show me how to correctly quote the variable or point me in a general direction? I read this stack overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-should-i-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and I'm still a little lost. Thanks.

Comment: If you're lost with bash, feel free to refer to its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html), especially when you have an idea as to what you're looking for.

Comment: In addition to which, the question you pointed to actually has examples. So what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Thanks. The manual helped. Any thoughts on my update^^?

Answer (score 0):

The only way around this that I can find is to save the json to a file and then reference it in the curl call -d "@"